# Sort array of hyperlinks by inner HTML

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, hyperlink, innerhtml

I have an array that is like this:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(116) "A" [1]=> string(112) "C" [2]=> string(110) "B" [3]=> string(115) "F" [4]=> string(113) "D" [5]=> string(112) "E" }
```

and which letter represents an Hyperlink, so each letter is:

```
<a href="link">Letter</a>
```

I want to sort this array so I have it sorted by its letter/innerHTML

I want to sort this before echoing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are all the hrefs actually different? Just making sure I understand properly.

Comment: Yes, they are all different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the links and create new associative array using letter as key and full link as value. Try below code.

```
$links=['<a href="link">D</a>','<a href="link">B</a>','<a href="link">C</a>','<a href="link">A</a>'];
    $new_links=[];
    foreach($links as $link){
        $array_1= explode(">",$link);
        $array_2 = explode("<",$array_1[1]);    
        $new_links[$array_2[0]]=$link;
    }
     ksort($new_links);
```

Comment: Great!! It does solve the question. One small problem is that when a link is selected, its key value becomes null. Any idea? Thank you!!

Comment: I am not clear what do you mean by "when a link is selected". Can you put a sample array for that case?

Answer (score 0):

You can `usort` with a callback that compares just the link text.

```
$link = '/.+>(.+)<.+/';    
usort($array, function($a, $b) use ($link) {
    return preg_replace($link, '\1', $a) <=> preg_replace($link, '\1', $b);
    // If you're on PHP 5 without the <=> operator, you can use strcmp instead
    // return strcmp(preg_replace($link, '\1', $a), preg_replace($link, '\1', $b));
});
```

I'm not a regex expert, so there's probably a better way to write the pattern, but the general idea is the same regardless. It's common knowledge that it's not a good idea to parse arbitrary HTML with regex, but for something like an array of `<a>` tags it seems pretty har̴ml҉es͝s.

Comment: I'll try this, but seems like php 7. I need 5 atm. Thanks

Comment: @GabrielG It's still doable on PHP 5. You can use `strcmp` instead of `<=>` (or `strcasecmp` for case-insensitive comparison).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using strip_tags() and sorting the result although if you want to preserve multiple link instances you need to use a multidimensional array and sort that:

```
$unsortedArray = [
  '<a href="/orange">Orange</a>',
  '<a href="/banana2">Banana</a>',
  '<a href="/apple">Apple</a>',
  '<a href="/pineapple">pineapple</a>',
  '<a href="/banana">Banana</a>',
  '<a href="/apple">Apple 2</a>',
];

$sortedArray = [];

function sortLinks($links) {
  $splitArray = [];
  $sortedArray = [];

  foreach($links as $link) {
    $label = strip_tags($link);
    $splitArray[] = ['link' => $link, 'label' => $label];
  }

  usort($splitArray, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['label'] <=> $b['label'];
  });

  foreach ($splitArray as $item) {
    $sortedArray[] = $item['link'];
  }

  return $sortedArray;
}

$sorted = sortLinks($unsortedArray);

echo '<pre>' . print_r($sorted, 1) . '</pre>';
```

The output should be:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Apple
    [1] => Apple 2
    [2] => Banana
    [3] => Banana
    [4] => Orange
    [5] => pineapple
)
```